# Sorting list of maps based on a value

Tags: java

I have a list of maps as follows

> [[AdGenres-b:key:[177, 184],MusicalStyles-b:key:[30],SongTitle:[What
>   I've
>   Done],ArtistName:[LinkinPark],MusicVideoRating:[TV-14],MusicalStyles-b:value:[Rock],PlayId:[1367],AdGenres-b:value:[Rock
>   - Rock, Rock - Alternative],MusicVideoProvider:[Warner Music Group],
>   AssetId:[91744]],
>
> [[AdGenres-b:key:[177, 184],MusicalStyles-b:key:[30],SongTitle:[What
>   I've Done],ArtistName:[Linkin Park],MusicVideoRating:[TV-14],
>   MusicalStyles-b:value:[Rock], PlayId:[1360], AdGenres-b:value:[Rock -
>   Rock, Rock - Alternative], MusicVideoProvider:[Warner Music Group],
>   AssetId:[91740]]

I want to sort the map by PlayId in ascending order and then store the sorted maps in a list.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: *I want to sort the map*, you mean "sort the *list*", right?

Answer (score 3):

Implement your own `Comparator<Map<Key, Value>>` based on `map.get("PlayId")`.

Example:

```
List<Map<String, String>> songs = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

songs.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("PlayId", "id3");
    put("Song Title", "some title");
}});

songs.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("PlayId", "id5");
    put("Song Title", "some title");
}});

songs.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("PlayId", "id2");
    put("Song Title", "some title");
}});

Collections.sort(songs, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
        return o1.get("PlayId").compareTo(o2.get("PlayId"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need a custom comparator.

Create a class that implements Comparator:

```
  class MyMapComparator {
    public int compare(Map m1, Map m2) {
      //get play id from both maps here and compare them
      return playId1 - playId2;
    }
  }
```

Then simply sort your list using instance of `MyMapComparator`.

```
Collections.sort(listTobeSorted, new MyMapComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the Map are present in list, songs
and if you don't want to use POJO entities.

```
List<Map<String, String>> songs = new ArrayList<>();

songs.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("PlayId", "id3");
    put("Title", "title3");
}});

songs.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("PlayId", "id2");
    put("Title", "title2");
}});

songs.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("PlayId", "id5");
    put("Title", "title5");
}});
```

use java.util.List.sort(Comparator<? super Map<String, String>> c

To sort in ascending order,

```
songs.sort( (a,b) -> a.get("PlayId").compareTo(b.get("PlayId")) );
```

if in descending order,

```
songs.sort( (a,b) -> b.get("PlayId").compareTo(a.get("PlayId")) );
```

Also, we could use custom function for Comparator.
if Comparator is null, then the natural order will be used