# Sort a list of maps by value in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have a list of maps. Which I cannot predict the key of each map. key can be an any two digits number which will change acordingly to the request.But values contains unique values from request to request.Now I need to sort this list of maps according to the value of each key. I've already tried something like bellow,

```
List<Map<String,String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("key1","value1");
map2.put("key2","value1");


listOfMaps.add(map1);
listOfMaps.add(map2);

sort(listOfMaps);

 Collections.sort(listOfMaps, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
        public int compare(final Map<String, String> o1, final Map<String, String> o2) {
            return o1.get("key").compareTo(o2.get("key"));
        }
    });
```

Since "key" can be differ from map to map, seems I couldnt use the above code.
I've also tried these examples.

[How to Sort a List of Maps by two Categories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474709/how-to-sort-a-list-of-maps-by-two-categories)

[Sorting list of maps based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167001/sorting-list-of-maps-based-on-a-value)

Since I'm cannot predict the key, I couldnt find an answer from these post.Can any one help with this?.

Comment: Do all of your maps only contain one entry?

Comment: I don't quite understand - maybe you can add a test case which demonstrates a sample input and what output you expect?

Comment: So are you sorting on the keys within all maps, or the values? And, are your sorting across all maps in the list?

Comment: @ Paul Boddington yep correct only one key and a value

Comment: @ pczeus Im trying to sort on the values. And yes all maps in the list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below example should work, under the assumption that each map element contains only one entry:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
//Add entries
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
    public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
        Collection<String> values1 = o1.values();
        Collection<String> values2 = o2.values();
        if(!values1.isEmpty() && !values2.isEmpty()){
            return values1.iterator().next().compareTo(values2.iterator().next());
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like this may be on the right track, except that it only checks the first value, not all values in the map.

Comment: Yes, I have specified that in my answer, have a look at 'under the assumption' part :)

Comment: @ Darshan Thanks it's worked, thank you very much.Second o1 should be o2 :)

Answer (score 1):

While it is occasionally necessary to create a `Map` with only one key and one value (`Collections.singletonMap` is used for this), it doesn't look like `Map` is appropriate for your situation. It makes much more sense to use a custom class with two fields, something like this:

```
// This is immutable. You may prefer to make fields non-final and add setters.
// You may also want to override equals() and hashCode().
final class StringPair {

    private final String key;
    private final String value;

    StringPair(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + key + ", " + value + "]";
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<StringPair> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new StringPair("K2", "V2"));
list.add(new StringPair("K1", "V1"));     
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<StringPair>() 
    @Override
    public int compare(StringPair o1, StringPair o2) {
        return o1.value.compareTo(o2.value);
    }     
});
System.out.println(list);    // Prints [[K1, V1], [K2, V2]]
```

Comment: @ Paul, Thanks, but in my case I have to use maps.. :)